# why dot file is generated rather jpg file in Ruby Graph Library (RGL)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-rgl

I have written the following code. When I run this file **graph.dot** file is generated 
rather than **graph.jpg**.
I can't understand why so. Does any body have any idea?

My code is as:

**`require 'rgl/adjacency'` 

`require 'rgl/dot'` 

`dg=RGL::DirectedAdjacencyGraph[1,2,2,3,2,4,4,5,6,4,1,6]`

`dg.write_to_graphic_file('jpg')`**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RGL uses dot files as an intermediary format to produce image formats, it doesn't produce them itself. That is why you are seeing a **graph.dot** file.

If you have a dot binary available (part of the [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) package), rgl will invoke it to produce a **graph.jpg** file.

You can download the [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) package at the project homepage, or use homebrew (if you're on a mac) to install it with `brew install graphviz`.